# no output in python test log panel in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use pytest to test my codes. The debug of the unit test can print the output to the debug console. But I just run the unit test, no output is printed to the python test log panel.
here is setting of pytest:

```
"python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
  "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "-s"
  ],
```

[python test log panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIhYK.png)
[test results panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RYQl.png)

I already set the `pytestArgs` parameter and took a look of other panels. There are no outputs of test in anywhere.

Comment: How are you calling your tests?

Comment: I just run the test in testing tab in vscode with the run button

Comment: Please learn to run tests from the command line...the real way tests are run. I'm not sure what could be wrong with your IDE. `pytest location/to/code/ -s` is all you need

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I have no problem here. https://imgur.com/XbHMONV.png    https://imgur.com/6jrYNDF.png